# How to return null value when using CopyToDataTable() LINQ extension method

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to return null value if there are no elements after executing my query, I am using DefaultIfEmpty() method, but it is not preventing from that exception to be thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
>
> Additional information: The source contains a DataRow reference that
>   is null.

my code:

```
DataTable filtered = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(x => x.Field<string>("SLA") == "Valid" 
                                   && x.Field<string>("Status") == "Finished")
                       .Select(y => y)
                       .DefaultIfEmpty()
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```

How can i return null value to `filtered` datatable?

Comment: May you use try catch ?

Comment: @Youssef13 I prefer to avoid try-catch blocks for resource efficiency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` returns an initialized collection with a default value'd item and not a `null` as you want:

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the type parameter's default value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

What you can do instead is just check the amount of items:

```
DataTable filtered = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(x => x.Field<string>("SLA") == "Valid" 
                                   && x.Field<string>("Status") == "Finished")
                       .Select(y => y)
                       .CopyToDataTable();

if(filtered.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    filtered = null;
}
```

---

Or better:

```
var collection = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(x => x.Field<string>("SLA") == "Valid" 
                               && x.Field<string>("Status") == "Finished")
                   .Select(y => y);
DataTable filtered = collection.Any() ? collection.CopyToDataTable() : null;
```

Comment: thank you, the second option is the answer, i think that the first option will still throw an exception, because its suppose  to be null.

Comment: @jonathana - I also think the second is better but the first will not throw as it will not be null but an empty collection

Comment: I wish downvoters would explain..